# Session timeout confusion - session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0)

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, glassfish, session-timeout

I am new to JEE and this is what confuses me. According to [HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29) documentation

> An `interval` value of `zero` or less indicates that the **session should never timeout**.

but according to my text book (which already is few years old - so I expect it not to be always right) using zero as argument should cause session to timeout immediately.

This code

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("foo", 42);
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);

        out.println(session.getAttribute("foo"));//problem here

    }
}
```

used on Glassfish 4.0 seems to confirm theory from textbook instead of newer official documentation because it returns *HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error* with error message

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated`

What is going on here? Is this Glassfish 4.0 bug or documentation is wrong? Or maybe there is third option?

---

PS. This code works as it should with negative values (session is not invalidated) and I am using `-1` instead of `0` in my code. I am just interested what is wrong with `0`.

Comment: The code works on Tomcat 7. Try with `-1`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. `-1` works fine and since it seems safer I am using it instead of `0`. I am just curious what is wrong with zero.

Comment: What happens if you set the `session-config` `session-timeout` value to 0 in web.xml?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis When I remove `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);` from code and use `<session-config><session-timeout>0</session-timeout></session-config>` in `web.xml` it seems to be working fine (session is not destroyed). What is interesting `session.getMaxInactiveInterval()` returns `-60` (in seconds) so it seems that value of `session-timeout` is converted to `-1` (in minutes)

Comment: Yes that config is in minutes while `setMaxInactiveInterval` is in seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) chapter on Session Timeouts states

> By definition, if the time out period for a session is set to -1,  the
>   session will never expire.

So GlasshFish seems to have that covered. I can't find any reference in the specification that says that the same should be true for a value of `0` with `setMaxInactiveInterval()`. However it does say

> The `session-config` defines the session parameters for this Web
>   application.  The sub-element `session-timeout` defines the default
>   session time out interval  for all sessions created in this Web
>   application. The specified time out must be expressed in a whole
>   number of minutes. **If the time out is 0 or less**, the container ensures
>   the default behavior of sessions is never to time out. If this element
>   is not specified, the container must set its default time out period.

Comment: Thanks for specification link (I would upvote you only for that if I could). I assume that since `0` is undefined in specification for `setMaxInactiveInterval` but only for `<session-config>` Glassfish implemented it correctly (but not perfectly according to JavaDoc) so it is not a bug. Anyway you give probably best answer that non-glass-fish-emploee could give so will accept your answer. Tank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

This is already time out and invalidate

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0); // mean inactive immediately
```

So this is correct error message. (please refer head first book for further reference.)

You are trying to access object value which is not exist. it's already destroyed

Comment: Yes, I know that *HF - servlets and JSP* shows that for argument `0` session will be invalidated immediately, but in official documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29 we can read that "An interval value of **zero** or less indicates that the *session should never timeout*." which was source of my confusion.