# When will a never expiring session in Glassfish will be destroyed?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 3 and I want a session to never expire, as long, as the browser window is open. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4502/beaxr/index.html) it is possible to adjust the `session-timeout` in the `web.xml`. I could set it to 0 and it would never expire.

But I am not secure about, what that means. Assumed the user is logged in and after some hours he simply closes the browser window. Whats happening in that case to the session at the server? Will it be an anonymous session, which remains in the memory, or will it be killed nevertheless from Glassfish? Or will it just be destroyed when the user explicitly do a logout?

So, when will Glassfish invalidate a never expiring session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the word already describes it: never.

From the servlet spec:

> By definition, if the time out period for a session is set to -1, the
>   session will never expire.

You can also read this in the docs of [HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29).

And:

> The session-config defines the session parameters for this Web
>   application. The sub-element session-timeout defines the default
>   session time out interval for all sessions created in this Web
>   application. The specified time out must be expressed in a whole
>   number of minutes. **If the time out is 0 or less, the container ensures**
>    **the default behavior of sessions is never to time out.** If this element
>   is not specified, the container must set its default time out period.

Regarding:

> Assumed the user is logged in and after some hours he simply closes
>   the browser window. Whats happening in that case to the session at the
>   server? Will it be an anonymous session, which remains in the memory,
>   or will it be killed nevertheless from Glassfish? Or will it just be
>   destroyed when the user explicitly do a logout?

The server (in most cases) doesn't know and doesn't care about if your browser window is open or not, so closing a browser window doesn't change anything of the session state. The session will just remain in memory of Glassfish until the application is un/redeployed or the application server is shutdown.

**See also:**

- [Session timeout confusion - session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064035/session-timeout-confusion-session-setmaxinactiveinterval0)
- [JBoss Wiki HttpSessionTimeout](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HttpSessionTimeout)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read the other thread. But I am just wondering why anyone should use a never expiring session, when it simply loads the memory over time? But maybe I don't get exactly how sessions are working. Assume someone shut down his pc and comes one day later back to the site. Will the session will be recovered from memory or a new one instantiated? Is it simply identifying with cookies? I think, I have to read more about how sessions work.

Comment: Yes the session is identified with cookies. But most web applications use a so called session cookie, this cookie gets deleted when the browser is closed. If you reopen the browser and visit your web application a new session will be created and you get a new cookie, but the old session is also kept in memory of the server.